# Rare event as categorical predictors - avoiding bias

Tags: regression, logistic, weighted-regression, rare-events

Are there rules to determine when a binary categorical variable is unfit to be included in a regression model due to extreme rarity in one of the levels of the variable? For example, a binary predictor variable with 1990 blues and 10 reds; or even worse 1999 blues and 1 red.

Currently, I'm constructing contingency tables with these rare events predictor variables and the response variable, then estimating the expected counts of the table and only consider such variables in my regression model if the expected counts are all greater than zero and none of the actual cell values is 0.

Note that the underlying regression model is design-based (survey-weighted logistic regression) and there are currently no penalized likelihood functions as in regular logistic regression

Comment: In your case are you interested in model selection or estimation only?

Comment: Model selection for the purpose of inference so I want to ensure that all parameters are estimable with reasonable effect sizes as well

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Note that the underlying regression model is design-based"

Comment: I meant to say I'm using a survey-weighted logistic regression for stratified sample. That is, logistic regression for survey data analysis (svyglm in R) but you can ignore this fact because I have same problem for "regular" logistic regression analysis